# im using a webview flutter for a website this is check as i am a native or not

Tags: webview, java.util.scanner

im using a webview for a website but there are a scanner in this website when i try to open it the website has a function that chack the platform and didnt see as my platform is android so how to make when the website check that i am native or not to be native and then access my native scanner code?? in flutter

also i have a chat in the website i want it to push a notification to the webview

NOte i cant edit in the website

i cant find a solution
i tried alot to chack how can i get any response from the website with no answer